# Mobile app device clould

Tags: integration-testing, mobile-application, mobile-app-tracker

I need some reference of device cloud provider where i can test my native mobile app developed. I have already found on one appthwack but was wondering if there are any better options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Testdroid - http://www.testdroid.com/ - over 400 Android and iOS devices, some for free.